# Save recorded sound to project file in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I recorded sound with the device's microphone but I don't know how to save it. Is it with the help of `MediaCapture` element, and if yes, then how to do it?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you searched on Google? What did you find? What didnt work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save MediaElement to project file in UWP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619966/save-mediaelement-to-project-file-in-uwp)

Comment: I did search for it but I haven't tried anything since I found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic idea how to convert to mp3 and save in a file with Datawriter.

I wrote this code on the fly so its not tested.

```
    MediaEncodingProfile _Profile = Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp3(AudioEncodingQuality.High);
    MediaTranscoder _Transcoder = new Windows.Media.Transcoding.MediaTranscoder();
    CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    private void ConvertSteamToMp3()
    {
        IRandomAccessStream audio = buffer.CloneStream(); //your recoreded InMemoryRandomAccessStream

        var folder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFolderAsync("MyCapturedAudio", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        outputFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync("record.mp3", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

        using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await outputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {

            var preparedTranscodeResult = await _Transcoder.PrepareStreamTranscodeAsync(audio, fileStream, _Profile);
            if (preparedTranscodeResult.CanTranscode)
            {
                var progress = new Progress<double>(TranscodeProgress);
                await preparedTranscodeResult.TranscodeAsync().AsTask(_cts.Token, progress);
            }

            using (IOutputStream outputStream = fileStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
            {
                using (DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter(outputStream))
                {
                    //TODO: Replace "Bytes" with the type you want to write.
                    dataWriter.WriteBytes(bytes);
                    await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
                    dataWriter.DetachStream();
                }

                await outputStream.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

Or just save the stream in a file

```
    public async SaveToFile()
{

    IRandomAccessStream audio = buffer.CloneStream(); //your recoreded InMemoryRandomAccessStream
    var folder  = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFolderAsync("MyCapturedAudio", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    outputFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync("record.mp3", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

        using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await outputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            await RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync(audio.GetInputStreamAt(0), fileStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0));
            await audio.FlushAsync();
            audio.Dispose();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I want to save it among the project files, specifically in /Assests/Sounds. Where can I change that?

Comment: You can use `StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;` I dont think its possible to save in assets its read only.